# Delay actions in android until a previous action has completed

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, sharedpreferences, firebase-authentication

The app I'm working on prompts for the user to log in using Firebase when the app is opened. If the app is completely closed, then upon opening it will take the user to the login screen. However, many of the workers at the company where I work don't close the app, they just send it to the background. That's a problem, because if I delete their account, it doesn't kick them out instantly; it only kicks them out once they close the app.

To fix this, I essentially coded the home screen such that every time the page reloads-whether coming to the foreground, returning home from a different activity, or starting up the app again-it logs the user out in the background, then re-logs them in, at which point it checks the validity of their user account.

The end goal of this is that if the user still has a valid login, they will be unaffected, but if they have an invalid login, they'll get locked out even if they haven't fully shut down the app.

However, currently the app kicks the user back to the login screen even with a valid login already entered.

Code for the Main Activity (login screen):

```
package com.priceelectric.xriley.priceprefab;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myDataStorage", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = prefs.edit();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user != null){
                    Log.d("loginTag", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                    Context context = getApplicationContext();

                    final Intent returnHome = new Intent();
                    returnHome.setClass(context, Home_Screen.class);
                    startActivity(returnHome);



                }
                else{
                    Log.d("loginTag", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }

            }
        };

        final EditText usernameTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameTextBox);
        final EditText passwordTextBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordTextBox);

        usernameTextBox.setText(prefs.getString("username", ""));
        passwordTextBox.setText(prefs.getString("password", ""));

        final Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        assert login != null;

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mEditor.putString("username", usernameTextBox.getText().toString());
                mEditor.putString("password", passwordTextBox.getText().toString());
                mEditor.commit();

                prefs.getInt("thing", 0);

                final String email = usernameTextBox.getText().toString();
                final String password = passwordTextBox.getText().toString();
//                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
//                final String uid = user.getUid();
//                final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myDataStorage", MODE_PRIVATE);
//                final SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = prefs.edit();
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                                Log.d("loginTag", "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                                if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Log.w("loginTag", "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        if(mAuthListener != null){
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence notificationText = "You need to log in.";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast.makeText(context, notificationText, duration).show();
    }

}
```

Code for the home screen:

```
package com.priceelectric.xriley.priceprefab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class Home_Screen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    FirebaseUser user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home__screen);

        final Button paperworkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.paperworkButton);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        final TextView versionLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.versionLabel);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myDataStorage", MODE_PRIVATE);

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(prefs.getString("username", ""), prefs.getString("password", ""));

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if(user != null){
            //all good
        }
        else{
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence notificationText = "You need to log in.";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast.makeText(context, notificationText, duration).show();

            final Intent loginScreen = new Intent();
            loginScreen.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(loginScreen);
        }

        if(prefs.getString("yourName", "").equals("")){
            final Intent settingsScreen = new Intent();
            settingsScreen.setClass(this, Settings_Screen.class);
            startActivity(settingsScreen);
        }
    }

    public void buttonOnClick(View view){

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myDataStorage", MODE_PRIVATE);

        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.prefabOrderButton:
                SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = prefs.edit();
                mEditor.putInt("itemNumberCounter", 0);
                mEditor.commit();

                final Intent prefabScreen = new Intent();
                prefabScreen.setClass(this, Prefab_Order.class);
                startActivity(prefabScreen);
                break;
            case R.id.safetyFormButton:
                final Intent safetyReportScreen = new Intent();
                safetyReportScreen.setClass(this, Safety_Report.class);
                startActivity(safetyReportScreen);
                break;
            case R.id.resiPanelButton:
                final Intent resiPanelScreen = new Intent();
                resiPanelScreen.setClass(this, Resi_Panel_Builder.class);
                startActivity(resiPanelScreen);
                break;
            case R.id.onlineResourcesButton:
                final Intent onlineResourcesScreen = new Intent();
                onlineResourcesScreen.setClass(this, Online_Resources.class);
                startActivity(onlineResourcesScreen);
                break;
            case R.id.settingsButton:
                final Intent settingsScreen = new Intent();
                settingsScreen.setClass(this, Settings_Screen.class);
                startActivity(settingsScreen);
                break;
            case R.id.paperworkButton:
                final Intent paperworkScreen = new Intent();
                paperworkScreen.setClass(this, Paperwork_Orders.class);
                startActivity(paperworkScreen);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Home_Screen` activity, I think you would get better results if you added a completion listener to `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`, similar to what you have in your `MainActivity`.

With the existing code:

```
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(prefs.getString("username", ""), prefs.getString("password", ""));

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if(user != null){
        //all good
    }
```

you are requesting the current user before the sign-in has completed, so `user` is null.

Add the completion listener and move the code to generate the toast and start `MainActivity` there, running it when `task.isSuccessful()` is false.

Also, instead of using sign-out/sign-in to test whether the user account is still valid, you might want to experiment with [FirebaseUser.reload()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#reload()).  The documentation indicates it returns a failure result if the current user account is disabled or deleted.

Use a completion listener to get the `reload()` status:

```
user.reload().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // account is still valid
        } else {
            // account is no longer valid
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I added the reload() command and a state change listener, but the reload() doesn't seem to trigger the listener.